# CSS in head over adding an id

Tags: html, css, head

I am working on responsive website that has 100's of pages. It is implemented using a CMS. The problem is, I need to apply some styling only for homepage.

It is a bit cumbersome to add a class or id in the CMS for one page as it uses templates to render pages.

I've added the css in the head section. The reason why I don't want to add in external file is beause the same id might be used on some other page.

Is adding CSS in head section a bad practice in this case.

```
<head>
    <style>
        //my css
    </style>
</head>
<body>


</body>
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about **inline** CSS? An inline `<style>` tag is **supposed** to go in the head. Including it anywhere **else** would be bad practice.

Comment: I've added in the head

Comment: Not necessarily. You could you add a class="home" to the container or body on the home page and build custom styles just for `.home.classname` in your css repository. That way you could use all the same styles except for when you add a customized class for the home page.

Comment: I do not think it is bad practice in your particular case. The point of having CSS in an external file is maintainability. To be able to modify that one file and have its results reflect across the site. In your case, that CSS is specific to the homepage, and therefore only needs to be changed seperately from the rest of the styling, so perhaps the homepage head tag is the best place for it. Not that there aren't any was to still use an external CSS file. You just don't really need it.

Comment: What CMS is this? There's probably a straightforward way to add a class on the <body> tag to identify it in your CSS.

Comment: There's really no such thing as "bad practice". There's "practices which should be avoided in most situations", but rarely are there "practices which must never be used". In this case, adding CSS in the head section is fine, *in my opinion*, but there is unlikely to be a specific answer to this question that is not based on opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to have inline CSS. Whether you should use inline CSS or simply set a unique ID for the page depends on the complexity and flexibility of the CMS you're using. Using inline CMS just means that you'll have to update the CSS from each individual page, rather than from a single source for all separate pages.

As for your second point, adding CSS to the head in a `<style>` tag is not bad practice. In fact, `<style>` is **required** to be a child of `<head>` in order to validate correctly. According to [the HTML 5.2 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/dom.html#the-style-attribute), `<style>` can be a child of any element as long as it it `scoped`, though at the present date, Firefox is [the only browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=style-scoped) that can use the `scoped` attribute.

On top of this, using a `<style>` tag in the `<body>` could lead to a [flash of unstyled content](http://web.archive.org/web/20150525042412/http://bluerobot.com/web/css/fouc.asp) due to the way in which the page gets loaded. So if you use inline CSS, always do so in the head to both validate correctly, and improve user experience :)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In a word yes. For reasons of maintainability. You would be better using the cascading nature of css to target a style specific to a specific page than to have lots of inline styles.

For example, consider:

```
<body class="my-page">
<h1 id="myId">Title</h1>


<body>
<h1 id="myId">Title</h1>

h1#myId{ font-size:12px; }
body.my-page h1#myId{ font-size:14px; }
```

the latter style will have precedence. h1#myId would be global, yet on a specific page you can override this style. Is there no way to work out what template is in use, and adjust the body class?

Comment: that's the hard part. Also, as lot of people work on the same website, I cannot be sure that someone hasn't used the same class/id or will use in the future

Answer (score 0):

If your CMS uses say PHP...
You could detect if you're in *homepage* and than call your custom external stylesheet, something like:

```
<?php
$page = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$isHomePage = $page==="/" || $page==="/index.php" || $page==="";

if( $isHomePage ) {
   echo '<link href="homepage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />';
} else {
   echo '<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />';
}
?>

</head>
```